# how to manage icons on area to the right of the address bar

Tags: google-chrome

There is an icon for "spam blocker," "readability", "instagram", "evernote", "pin", "pocket",and "pinterest" to the right of the address bar in Chrome on my MacBook Pro. I need to remove the "pin" icon and the "pinterest" icon because they do not seem to work. I've tried *delete*, *command delete* *shift command delete* and a couple other configurations.None of these work. How do I remove these icons?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+Click → *Remove from Chrome*

or

Menu button [image: Menu button] → *More tools* → *Extensions* → Trash can icon next to the extension you want to remove.